# how to return object instead of object in array

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to return a response of an object which came from a collection array due to a relation of hasMany.

I have tried to do a return `$block->where('date','=',$today)->first();`

> error said: Call to undefined method
>   App\BlockDate::addEagerConstraints()

```
public function block_dates() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(BlockDate::class);
}

public function schedule_block() 
{
    $today = Carbon::today()->toDateString();
    $block = $this->block_dates();

    return $block->where('date','=',$today)->first();
}
```

`schedule_block()` should return an object of `BlockDate`. If I remove `first()`, it returns an array with the desired object in. I would like to just retrieve the object based on the relation. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you  call `->schedule_block()` ?

Comment: Add ->toArray() at the end may be that helps to convert object into array

Comment: @Ijas schedule_block() is called from a controller with a with()
Joshi - I am trying to get the object, not to make it into an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one :

```
public function schedule_block() {
    $today = Carbon::today()->toDateString();
    return $this->hasOne(BlockDate::class)->where('date','=',$today);
}
```

Comment: @NewProgrammer , is it working ? or you receives any errors ?

Comment: yes it is working, but I am confused. Relation hasOne does not point to the first entry of BlockDates with schedule_id, which I thought it will. How does it work?

Comment: `block_dates()` uses hasMany relation with `BlockDate` class , which will return array() , but as you want to get only one record as object , so i used `hasOne` relationship with `BlockDate` class , which will return Object.

Comment: technically Schedule class hasMany relation with BlockDate class, yes which is why it returns an array. I am just puzzled at how where() works for hasOne. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: where will also work with `hasMany` , but it will return results as array not object

Comment: try this one : `public function schedule_block() 
{
    $today = Carbon::today()->toDateString();
    $block = $this->block_dates()->where('date','=',$today);
    if(count($block)>0){
      return $block[0];  
    } else{
      return null;
    }
}`

Comment: It shows an error for count() when array returns '[]'. I will stick with hasOne and where.